# Colab NOTEBOOK -> MARKDOWN > CHECKBOX.VALUE a VARIABLE DE NOTEBOOK? POSIBLE?

Tags: python

Hola amigos tengo una consulta, tengo el siguiente código que usa MARKDOWN para determinar ciertos valores del notebook antes de ejecutar la celda:

```
#@markdown <table><tr><td><input type="checkbox" checked id="t1">MyCell1</td><td><input type="checkbox" checked id="t2">MyCell2</td></tr><tr><td><input type="checkbox" checked id="t3">MyCell3</td><td><input type="checkbox" checked id="t4">MyCell4</td></tr></table>

#Lo que quiero hacer es poder hace una tabla con checkboxes para ue quede prolijo y ordenado que luego me permita ver si estan o no checked dentro de la ejecución de la celda en PYTHON, por ejemplo:

print(markdown.t1.value)
print(markdown.t2.value)
print(markdown.t3.value)
print(markdown.t4.value)
```

Agradezco su ayuda y predisposición

Comment: En lugar de escribir un título "acortado", escríbelo como _pregunta_. Lo mismo con el cuerpo. Esto no es un chat :) Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.